# Using operators (like <<) on shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have an FStream that because of other project constraints exists as a `std::shared_ptr<std::fstream>`.

I would like to write to this stream using the `<<` operator, but I cannot find the correct syntax for writing to the member of a shared pointer.

Comment: Dereference the `shared_ptr` first, as in `*sptr << data` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that more verbose and explicit:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::fstream> sf = ...;
std::ostream &out = *sf;
out << "hello world";
```

or simply:

```
*sf << "hello world";
```

Comment: What is the benefit of "verbose" way?

Comment: To make OP understand what is going under the hood and what type is usually used for implementing output functions.